# Querying for records that must contain a set of values in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a filtering system in a site on a set of records that can be tagged with multiple tags. Eventually I'd like the filter to support OR, AND, and NOT, but right now I'm just trying to get AND working.

Here are the entities with relevant properties, which is just a many to many relationship modeled in EF Core.

```
public class Record
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<RecordTag> RecordTags { get; set; }
}

public class RecordTag
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public Song Record { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecordTag> RecordTags { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to write an EF Core query as follows:

```
var tagList = tags.Split(',');
// tagList now contains the strings of tags the user has filtered on

Records = recordRepository.Query() // simply returns IQueryable<Records> 
          .Where(r=> tagList.All(  // For each record, iterate through all tags selected by the user
                t => r.RecordTags.Select(rt => rt.Tag.Name).Contains(t))) // For each user selected tag, get all the tags on the record and ensure it contains the tag we're iterating over
                .Include(r => r.RecordTags).ThenInclude(rt => rt.Tag).ToList(); // Include the tag data back with the parent entity.
```

However, this throws an error

> [query] could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

I'd prefer not to have to bring back a larger set and filter it on the application server, rather, having the query be built correctly directly against the DB.

Why is this query not valid? Is there another way to write this so it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add where conditions in a foreach loop.

```
var recordRepositoryQuery = recordRepository.Query();
foreach(var tag in taglist)
{       
   recordRepositoryQuery = recordRepositoryQuery.Where(r => r.RecordTags.Select(rt => rt.Tag.Name).Contains(tag))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense rather than trying to build it all in one where clause, and now I can see if someone creates a complex expression with ands, ors, and nots, I could build up the query dynamically this way.